# listview.builder updates/refreshes all items(icons) inside of its itembuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I do have a problem wherein it flickers an animation whenever the `heart icon` is changing from `normal heart icon` to `fill heart icon` vice-versa whenever the data is changing.

Here is my code for it, I named my stateless widget as `PostInteractionButtons` since I will be implementing the comment, and lastly the bookmark as well. Right now, only the like/dislike function is working.

**`widget_states.dart`**

```
class PostsInteracationButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  const PostsInteracationButtons(
      {Key? key, required this.isFeelsLiked, required this.feelsUid, this.getPostUid, required this.currentUserUid, required this.feelsAuthorId})
      : super(key: key);

  final bool isFeelsLiked;

  final String? feelsUid;
  final List<String>? getPostUid;
  final String currentUserUid;
  final String? feelsAuthorId;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<UsersLikesModel>>(
      // fetch the document field ``liked_posts`` by current logged in user.
        stream: FirestoreHelper.currentUserLikeButton("user_activities", currentUserUid, "likes"),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Container();
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Center(
              child: Text("snapshot has error!"),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
            print("snapshot.data: ${snapshot.data?.length}");
            return Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: const Center(
                child: Text(
                  "No posts/images posted by users...",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            final userLikesActivity = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //<--here
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: userLikesActivity?.length ?? 0,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final fetchLikedPostsByUser = userLikesActivity![index];
                  // final List<String> likedPosts = fetchLikedPostsByUser.likedPosts;
                  return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: .75.h, right: 3.w, left: 3.w),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        // post already liked by user..
                        // I think this is where the problem occurs, since I am using a ternary
                        // operator to change the heart from normal to filled(red)
                        fetchLikedPostsByUser.likedPosts!.contains(feelsUid)
                            ? GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  FirestoreHelper.dislikePostFunction(feelsUid!, feelsAuthorId!, currentUserUid);
                                },
                                child: Icon(
                                  OctIcons.heart_fill_16,
                                  size: 25,
                                  color: Colors.red.withOpacity(1),
                                  fill: 0.5,
                                  weight: .5,
                                ),
                              )
                            // post not yet liked by user..
                            : GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  FirestoreHelper.likePostFunction(feelsUid!, feelsAuthorId!, currentUserUid);
                                },
                                child: Icon(
                                  OctIcons.heart_16,
                                  size: 25,
                                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(1),
                                  fill: 0.5,
                                  weight: .5,
                                ),
                              ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 5.w,
                        ),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            print("comment");
                          },
                          child: Icon(
                            FontAwesome.comment,
                            size: 25,
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(1),
                            fill: 0.5,
                            weight: .5,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Spacer(),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            print("bookmarked");
                          },
                          child: Icon(
                            FontAwesome.bookmark,
                            size: 25,
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(1),
                            fill: 0.5,
                            weight: .5,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                });
          }
        });
  }
}
```

this happens to ALL heart icons of every post, whenever I try to tap the heart icon of post1, it will flicker as well with the heart icon of post2.

MORE INFO: I am calling the `PostsInteractionButtons`StatelessWidget inside of `ListView.Builder` of the `home_page` of every post, I genuinely do not know if that's the conflict.

**`home_page.dart`**

```
StreamBuilder<List<UserActivityModel>>(
                  stream: FirestoreHelper.readAll("posts"),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return const Center(
                        child: Text("An error has occured while fetching users posts."),
                      );
                    } else if (snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                      print("snapshot.data: ${snapshot.data?.length}");
                      return Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "No posts/images posted by users...",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                          ));
                    } else {
                      final userActivityPosts = snapshot.data;
                      return Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          ListView.builder(
                              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //<--here
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemCount: userActivityPosts?.length ?? 0,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                final fetchUserDetails = userActivityPosts![index];
                                return Column(children: [
                                  ListTile(
                                    leading: const SizedBox(
                                      child: CircleAvatar(
                                        radius: 21.5,
                                        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF6949FF),
                                        child: CircleAvatar(
                                          radius: 20,
                                          backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                                              "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520342868574-5fa3804e551c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6ff92caffcdd63681a35134a6770ed3b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80"),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    title: Text(
                                      "${fetchUserDetails.feelsUserHandler}",
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.sp),
                                    ),
                                    subtitle: Text(
                                      "${fetchUserDetails.feelsDatePosted}",
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 8.sp),
                                    ),
                                    trailing: const IconButton(
                                        onPressed: null,
                                        icon: Icon(
                                          Icons.more_vert,
                                          size: 20,
                                        )),
                                  ),
                                  CarouselSlider(
                                    options: CarouselOptions(),
                                    items: fetchUserDetails.feelsImages!
                                        .map(
                                          (item) => CachedNetworkImage(
                                            imageUrl: item,
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                            width: 1000,
                                            placeholder: (context, url) => const Center(
                                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                              strokeWidth: 0.7,
                                            )),
                                            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                        .toList(),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.2.h, left: 3.w),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        TextWidget(
                                            descriptionText: fetchUserDetails.usersWhoLiked!.contains(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid) &&
                                                    fetchUserDetails.usersWhoLiked!.length > 1
                                                ? "You, and ${fetchUserDetails.usersWhoLiked!.length - 1} other likes this. "
                                                : fetchUserDetails.usersWhoLiked!.contains(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid) &&
                                                        fetchUserDetails.usersWhoLiked!.length == 1
                                                    ? "You liked this post. "
                                                    : fetchUserDetails.usersWhoLiked!.isEmpty
                                                        ? "No one liked it yet"
                                                        : "${fetchUserDetails.usersWhoLiked!.length} other likes this. ",
                                            selectedFontColor: Colors.black,
                                            selectedFontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                            selectedFontSize: 9.5.sp),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                // here I calling the PostsInteracationButtons
                // as you can see above, I am calling this stateless widget
                // inside the ``ListView.Builder`` as well.
                                  PostsInteracationButtons(
                                      isFeelsLiked: true,
                                      feelsUid: fetchUserDetails.feelsPostUID,
                                      currentUserUid: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
                                      feelsAuthorId: fetchUserDetails.feelsAuthor),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 2.5.h,
                                  ),
                                ]);
                              })
                        ],
                      );
                    }
                  }),
```

Here is the GIF snippet for visual representation:

[image]